# Dygraphs change series name dynamically?

Tags: dygraphs

I have a dygraphs chart that has 115 or so series plotted on it.  It works great.  However, I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the series name of the highlighted series, and how to format that number.

Example on the dygraph fiddle page (though, I use a big php string for data, which won't be shown). http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/861/

I end up with a highlighted label of something like "Year: 1955 Y73 Portfolio: $1,000,000". I want to be able to retrieve that 73 number, and edit what it says.  I can't find in the dygraph js file a specific label formatter for the series number ,or a method to retrieve it. I don't want to have to label every series manually.

Ideas?   This is a great charting software.

```
gr = new Dygraph(
// containing div
document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
// CSV or path to a CSV file.
<?php echo $chartDataString2; ?>,
{
    title: 'Spending Level',
    ylabel: 'Spending ($)',
    xlabel: 'Year',
    labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
    digitsAfterDecimal: 0,
    yAxisLabelWidth: 100,
    axes: {
        y: {


                labelsKMB: false,
                maxNumberWidth: 11,
                valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return 'Spending: $' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                },
                axisLabelFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return '$' + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }
        },
        x: {
            valueFormatter: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    return 'Year: ' + x;
                },
        },
    },
    showLabelsOnHighlight: true,
    highlightCircleSize: 3,
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    strokeBorderWidth: 0,
 highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: 1.0,
    highlightSeriesOpts: {
      strokeWidth: 4,
      strokeBorderWidth: 2,
      highlightCircleSize: 5,
    },
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in dygraphs legend is good for most charts, but at some point you outgrow it. It sounds like you've reached that point. I'd suggest hiding the built-in legend and implementing your own using highlightCallback and unhighlightCallback. You can get access to the series names via g.getLabels().

Comment: Hmm. I'm not much of a javascript developer. I've been hacking my graphs together using examples.  Though, it appears that a solution to my problem might be just creating a "labels:" string in php during the process that I create my data string.... I think.